# User controller from other codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have to host my Code Igniter project on my client's server. But i don't want to give access to my code. So it is possible to take access of controllers which is hosted on my domain.

If possible, then how to configure config.php file and routes.php file

Please help me.

Comment: No you cant. Change Host password. That's it you can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Zend Guard you protect your code:

> - Limiting unauthorized duplication or use of your applications.
> - Ensuring that only licensed customers use your products and that they remain within the terms of your license.
> - Offering flexible licensing terms that make your software products more attractive, increase sales, and improve customer satisfaction.
> - Increasing conversion rate from evaluation to licensed product.
> - **Preventing other people from changing your code (all files are rendered as un-editable and external changes will corrupt the code) protecting the files against external tampering.**

More information and video's about PHP encoding: http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard

Comment: Encoding code by ZEND Gaurd, @server side any zend support is required?

Comment: See the system requirements here: http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard#requirements

Comment: Thanks a lot @Henri S.

Answer (score 1):

You can `Encrypt a PHP script`. PHP has `BLENC` libarary to Encrypt the plaintext content and write it into encodedfile.

**Example `blenc_encrypt()` example**

```
<?php

/* read the PHP source code */
$source_code = file_get_contents("my_source_to_protect.php");

/* create the encrypted version */
$redistributable_key = blenc_encrypt($source_code, "my_source_encoded.php");

/* read which is the key_file */
$key_file = ini_get('blenc.key_file');

/* save the redistributable key */
file_put_contents($key_file, $redistributable_key, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.blenc-encrypt.php)

**NOTE** There are alot of ways to encrypt PHP code.

You could also use the below tools to achieve the same.

- [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/)
- [IonCube](http://www.ioncube.com/php_encoder.php)
- [SourceGuardian](http://www.sourceguardian.com/text-features-page-160.html)
- [phpSHIELD](http://www.phpshield.com/)

But these 'others' can also decode/decrypt the source code using other tools and services found online. So you cannot 100% protect your code, what you can do is, make it tougher for someone to reverse engineer your code.

Most of these tools above support Encoding and Obfuscating.

- Encoding will hide your code by encrypting it.
- Obfuscating will make your code difficult to understand.

You can choose to use both (Encoding and Obfuscating) or either one, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like I want to sell my house but try to keep my bricks from it. It is not possible in case of web development.

Comment: In case of Premium Product selling you are right; but initially i provide them to free of cost to test.